# What’s the form of Gram matrix for right-angled hexagon

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Informally, right-angled hyperbolic hexagon is a hyperbolic triangle with vertices outside infinity. I think there should be a Gram matrix for it, and **what does it looks like?**
(The Gram matrix here defines the existence of a simplex)

Also, for hyperbolic truncated tetrahedron or hyperbolic truncated n-simplex what’s the form of its Gram matrix?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of Gram matrix in this context?

Comment: @j.c. It defines the existence of a simplex. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you mean by "what is the form"? And which Gram matrix? (there are two). But if you mean the usual Gram matrix, then the $ij$ element is $-\cosh d(s_i, s_j),$ where $s_i$ is the $2i$-th side of the hexagon.